# Add huge number of records to server

Tags: php, mysql

We have a eCommerce system and we have a inventory system separate. we use php and mysql. We need to us the inventory details to the eCommerce server. We have around 7500 records to be pushed to server every 1 hr. We had created a api on Ecommerce system through which we were adding the inventory. But it is taking loot of time as both servers are in different location. Is there a faster method by which we can push this inventory to server. i.e. add records to particular table on server and only 2 columns.

Comment: Would a flat file work?

Comment: How exactly is this import API working? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Thomas Hambach - The api was a simple insert into table. so we had to loop through it as many number of records we had.

Comment: @Hacker Is it not possible to directly create and execute MySQL queries from your data instead of handling the import with PHP?

Comment: You might see if `rsync` could help somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their must be lot of options for MySQL side like rsync, LOAD DATA INFILE, INSERT MULTIPLE ROWS (as Thomas says) etc.

For PHP Side you can use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) which should be faster. Here you only bind params and execute in loop. While query definition is out side of loop.
But Still MySQL solutions must be more effective in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us where the bottleneck is? Is your API being held up by the database? How many items are you pushing through the API in a single call?

Comment: In a single call only 1 record was pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing one API request per row in the table. This introduces **a lot** of overhead.

Instead, make either a huge request with the 7.500+ rows (not good but still better than 1/1), or several requests of `n` records. Tailor `n` according to performance.

## Edit

Since you never named your e-commerce solution, I'm assuming it's in-house and you can tinker with the API. If this is not true, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, if you add tons of data in a single table you can do a single `INSERT` for multiple `ROWS`. It's much much faster that way.

```
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (2, 'Lamp'), (1, 'Bike'), (8, 'TV');
```

You can find documentation about `INSERT` optimization in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html).

The documentation also shows alternative solutions that you might want to consider.

Comment: @ Thomas Potaire - problems is that server is in different location and we cannot touch database directly.

Comment: I see... so you are using a third-party solution to inject data in the DB? Can you ask them to provide an API call that allows single insert with multiple rows? If you don't have any access to the DB it's going to be really really tough..